# Is there any example app that uses system managed ConnectionService

Tags: android-connectionservice

According to [ConnectionService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/ConnectionService) API, we can make calling apps with system managed ConnectionService. Does it mean the calling app will use system calling UI? Is there any example app like this in the store?